# summable square function implies...?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I have difficulty to demonstrate this:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)|^2dx<\infty~~~\text{(summable square function)}$$ 
then,

$$\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty }f(x)=0$$

thank you.

Comment: Could it be the reverse, i.e., $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |f(x)|^2 dx < \infty => \lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x) = 0$?

Comment: yes, yes, it is well

Answer (score 3):

You are probably having difficulties because this fact is false: The function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x \in \mathbb Z \\0 & x \notin \mathbb Z \end{cases}$$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Yes. One can construct counterexamples even if $f$ is assumed to be continuous.

Comment: @AymanHourieh smooth $f$s are possible as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just take a function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{n^2+1}(x-n)^{-1/3}, \quad x\in (n,n+1]$$
for $n\in \Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Define ${\rm J}\left(x\right) \equiv \int_{-\infty}^{x}\left\vert{\rm f}\left(x'\right)\right\vert^{2}\,{\rm d}x'$. Then, $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists\ N, N'$
such that $\left(x + h\right) > N$ and $x > N'\quad\Longrightarrow$

$$
\left\vert{\rm J}\left(x + h\right) - {\rm J}\left(x\right)\right\vert
\leq
\underbrace{\quad\left\vert{\rm J}\left(x + h\right) - {\rm J}\left(\infty\right)\right\vert\quad}
_{<\ \epsilon\,/\,2}
+
\underbrace{\quad\left\vert{\rm J}\left(x\right) - {\rm J}\left(\infty\right)\right\vert\quad}
_{<\ \epsilon\,/\,2}
<
\epsilon
$$

Then, $\forall\ \epsilon >0$; when $x > {\rm max}\left\lbrace N - h, N'\right\rbrace$, we have
$\left\vert{\rm J}\left(x + h\right) - {\rm J}\left(x\right)\right\vert < \epsilon$. That
means

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\left\vert{\rm J}\left(x + h\right) - {\rm J}\left(x\right)\right\vert
=
0
$$

Also

$$
0
=
\lim_{h \to 0}\lim_{x \to \infty}
\left\vert{{\rm J}\left(x + h\right) - {\rm J}\left(x\right) \over h}\right\vert
=
\lim_{x \to \infty}\lim_{h \to 0}
\left\vert{{\rm J}\left(x + h\right) - {\rm J}\left(x\right) \over h}\right\vert
=
\lim_{x \to \infty}\
\left\vert{\rm f}\left(x\right)\right\vert^{2}
$$

We have to be sure we can exchange the limits. That puts an extra condition on ${\rm J}\left(x\right)$ or/and ${\rm f}\left(x\right)$.